# How to get ComboBox.SelectedText in WPF

Tags: wpf

In WPF ComboBox does not have SelectedText property.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality as TextBox SelectedText has in WPF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get access to the ComboBox's TextBox by using:

```
var edit = (TextBox)myCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myCombo);
```

Then you can access the SelectedText property of that TextBox:

```
var selectedText = edit.SelectedText;
```

Comment: This only works if your ComboBox is already shown (i.e. it is generated from its ControlTemplate), so you can't do something like create a ComboBox and focus on its TextBox immediately

Answer (score 1):

Because WPF is "lookless" you can display your combobox items in any manner you wish.  there may or may not be a text item.

`MyCombo.SelectedText` doesn't make any sense if you are, for example, display icons in there.

What you want is    `ComboBox.SelectedItem` and then access your object.  for example, if you are using a backing list of "People" objects.... `MyComboBox.SelectedItem.PersonName`

typically, the SelectedItem is databound to your object model or to another control.

Comment: I got the answer in the above Post. I need SelectedText from the ComboBox to process them further, When ComboBox is in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called the selectedText but you can achive that by `ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()` method. It's because the values of an combobox is by default of the type Object so we have to suitably typecast it.

Comment: The is not completely true. If you are using a custom item template, your code will not match the rendered string. Ideally, you should be so you can, for example, put Employee objects in the list instead of a bunch of custom generated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ComboBoxItem Item = (ComboBoxItem) YourComboBoxName.SelectedValue;
```

Then this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Item.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't You Try :

```
string selectedtext= Combobox.Text;
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
(string)comboBox.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayMemberPath).GetValue(comboBox.SelectedItem);
```