# Display the text selected in a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Any help would be useful. I'm trying to display the text that is selected in my ComboBox in WPF.

This is the code I have:

```cs
MessageBox.Show(combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

However this outputs: `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem : Art/Leisure`

I would like it to output: `Art/Leisure`

I'm not sure what I should be doing differently!

Comment: Is this a partial selection or do you just want the _text representation of the selected object_ as it is displayed in the combo box? A screenshot might help. If this is not a partial text related request, then the dup is wrong.

Comment: let us know if you disagree with the duplicate closure by editing to include some snippets of code and perhaps a screenshot to further identify the text that you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

### Text Content from the Selected Item

If you are using a simple `ComboBox` with `ComboBoxItem`s defined in xaml, then you may only need this:

```
MessageBox.Show((combobox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString());
```

The `SelectedItem` property gives you access to the instance of the *object* that is selected, depending on the rendering templates used and how or if you have *bound* the items to the combo the above may no work.

If you cannot guarantee that the item is the *type* you are expeceting I encourage you to use pattern matching in scenarios like this instead of direct casting. The resulting code becomes more extensible when you need to handle cases like `null` (no selection) or when the SelectedItem is a data bound record (and so *not* a `ComboBoxItem`)

```
if (combobox1.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem cbItem)
    MessageBox.Show($"{cbItem.Content}");
// example of an alternate expected type pattern:
//else if (combobox1.SelectedItem is MyWidget widget)
//    MessageBox.Show(widget.Description);
else
    MessageBox.Show($"{combobox1.SelectedItem}");
```

### Selected Text in an editable ComboBox:

if you specifically want to access the text that is partially selected in the ComboBox, then according to this advice [How to get ComboBox.SelectedText in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169358/1690217)
You should be able to access the selected text by accessing the internal TextBox that is used in the control template for the combo box:

var textBox = (TextBox)combobox1.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combobox1);
MessageBox.Show(textBox.SelectedText);

---

### Background - TextBox selected text:

Have a read at this WPF tutorial: [The TextBox Control](https://wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textbox-control/)

[image]

```
txtStatus.Text = "Selection starts at character #" + textBox.SelectionStart + Environment.NewLine;
txtStatus.Text += "Selection is " + textBox.SelectionLength + " character(s) long" + Environment.NewLine;
txtStatus.Text += "Selected text: '" + textBox.SelectedText + "'";
```

> **SelectionStart** gives us the current cursor position or if there's a selection: Where it starts.
> **SelectionLength** gives us the length of the current selection, if any. Otherwise it will just return 0.
> **SelectedText** gives us the currently selected string if there's a selection. Otherwise an empty string is returned.

Comment: Was it partial select in the end or just the whole item?